# CSS processing order

Tags: html, css

I'm at odds with my boss over CSS processing order.

Boss insists that order of selectors in CSS file should match the order in which those selectors are used  in calling web pages. He claims that such structuring is forced by browsers which read CSS file content sequentially and apply the rules in that sequence.

I think this is wrong.

If my programming experience has any relevance to CSS application, and I am .NET programmer, browsers read CSS files first and for each selector a memory reference (pointer akin method memory reference) is created and then, as the browser reads html file and renders a page, each time a selector is used, browser references appropriate memory address with style rule and applies changes while final result is being rendered in DOM. The sequence in CSS file is irrelevant.

I can't support my claim with any documentation. Does anyone know where I could find technical documentation regarding this and prove me right or wrong?
Is there a rule to how to organize CSS file?

Comment: Specificity of the CSS rules is what determines how they're rendered. That, and the dreaded `!important` rule. Your boss is definitely wrong about the "order of selectors in CSS file should match the order in which those selectors are used in calling web pages" though.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/How_CSS_works

maybe he works on CSS when that rule was applyed, before all the new stuff   on CSS architecture. BEM, OOCSS, etc.

Comment: your boss is incorrect, selectors should be loaded in order of specificity, with global styles, then module styles, then page specific styles, then hacks (if you need them) - each set gets slightly more specific and over-rides the last, however, if you're really clever with your naming conventions and fully understand specificity, the order of the selectors becomes a lot less relevant, your boss could be a top notch css dev who can't express themselves well :-)

Comment: Your question is confusing. Could you provide an example of *wrong* and *right* order of CSS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The order matters, but only when the specificity is equal.

e.g.

```
.one { color: black; }
.two { color: red; }
```

with

```
<div class="one two">...</div>
```

… will be different depending on which order the CSS rulesets appear in.

See [the cascade](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascading-order) for more detail.

Comment: ...   and any good design *should* avoid this situation (having 2 conflicting classes fight each other, relying only on the order)